# Biblatex: online isbn versus print isbn

Tags: biblatex

The following [book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-75392-6/page/1) is referenced through two distinct isbn numbers: the online isbn and the print isbn. Is there a way to reflect this with biblatex?

```
@BOOK{AcaryBrogliato201011, 
  title={Numerical Methods for Nonsmooth Dynamical Systems: Applications in Mechanics   and Electronics (Lecture Notes in Applied and Computational Mechanics)},
  author={Vincent Acary and Bernard Brogliato},
  publisher={Springer},
  date={2010},
  month={11},
  edition={Softcover reprint of hardcover 1st ed. 2008},
  isbn_online={9783540753926},
  isbn_print={9783642094644},
  url={http://amazon.de/o/ASIN/3642094643/},
  price={EUR 245,03},
  totalpages={548},
  timestamp={2013.04.25},
}
```

Comment: I think you can reflect everything. The question is what's your idea? ;-)

Comment: Why not just use the ISBN for the copy you're actually citing? If you insist on both the `isbn` field is of the literal type so you can do list processing with `\forcsvfield`. You can also extend the default data model to make `isbn` of the list type. There was some discussion of this at the github repo.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I would like to reference the two numbers. I am not sure it makes sense though.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks, I'll try to have a look at this possibility.

Comment: @pluton: Could you solve your issue?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: not really. I have to find time first.

Comment: @Audrey A short answer would be nice. A MWE would be even better.

Comment: The texnical perspective aside, I wonder if you should do that. IIRC, print vs online counts as different editions and should therefore probably be cited separatedly. While kind of a nuisande, it *can* be important if e.g. page numbers differ, or the electronic version receives an update without a new printing (would it get a new ISBN?). That is, it may be important which version you cite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NB: `biber` is needed to (fully) enjoy the following code.

To let `BibLaTeX` deal with online and print ISBNs, we need register the fields in a datamodel file, the easiest way is to create a `<style>.dbx` in the working directory.

```
\ProvidesFile{authortitle.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{isbnonline}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{isbnprint}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{isbnonline,isbnprint}
```

Now `biber` and `BibLaTeX` know the field, we need to get `BibLaTeX` to print it in a nice format

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbnonline}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}~(online)\addcolon\space #1}% we need some format ..
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbnprint}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}~(print)\addcolon\space #1}% ... just stole it from standard ISBN
```

We just patch the bibliography drivers to also print our online and print ISBN.
With the following command patching a driver (that includes `\printfield{isbn}`) is as easy as `\patchmoreisbn{book}`.

```
\newcommand*{\patchmoreisbn}[1]{% let all drivers include the isbn
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}%
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {\printfield{isbn}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{isbnprint}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{isbnonline}}%
    {\typeout{patching #1 to include more ISBNs succeded}}%
    {\typeout{patching #1 to include more ISBNs failed}}%
}
```

The full MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch the editor macros
\usepackage[style=authortitle, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{authortitle.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{authortitle.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{isbnonline}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{isbnprint}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{isbnonline,isbnprint}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{AcaryBrogliato201011, 
  title       = {Numerical Methods for Nonsmooth Dynamical Systems},
  subtitle    = {Applications in Mechanics and Electronics},
  titleaddon  = {Lecture Notes in Applied and Computational Mechanics},
  author      = {Vincent Acary and Bernard Brogliato},
  publisher   = {Springer},
  date        = {2010},
  month       = {11},
  edition     = {1},
  isbnonline  = {978-3-540-75392-6},
  isbnprint   = {978-3-642-09464-4},
}
@book{Heuser:Analysis1,
  author    = {Harro Heuser},
  title     = {Lehrbuch der Analysis Teil 1},
  edition   = {17., aktualisierte},
  date      = {2009},
  gender    = {sm},
  isbn      = {978-3-8384-0777-9},
  publisher = {Vieweg+Teubner},
  location  = {Wiesbaden},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{isbnonline}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}~(online)\addcolon\space #1}% we need some format ..
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbnprint}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}~(print)\addcolon\space #1}% ... just stole it from standard ISBNa
\newcommand*{\patchmoreisbn}[1]{% let all drivers include the isbn
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}%
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {\printfield{isbn}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{isbnprint}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{isbnonline}}%
    {\typeout{patching #1 to include more ISBNs succeded}}%
    {\typeout{patching #1 to include more ISBNs failed}}%
}
% patch all drivers
\patchmoreisbn{article}
\patchmoreisbn{book}
\patchmoreisbn{collection}
\patchmoreisbn{inbook}
\patchmoreisbn{incollection}
\patchmoreisbn{inproceedings}
\patchmoreisbn{manual}
\patchmoreisbn{periodical}
\patchmoreisbn{proceedings}
\patchmoreisbn{report}
\patchmoreisbn{thesis}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces
[image: bibliography with two ISBNs]