# Several strings in one biblatex-field -- multiple references

Tags: biblatex, biber

As I understand it, biblatex-fields as `eprint` and `related` accept one and only string/key, though I want them to refer to two or more items/addresses.

To give an example which might make it clear what I mean (the example needs three runs: latex --> biber --> latex):

```
\begin{filecontents}{MyBib.bib}
@Article{Barney:Notes,
  author =   {Rachel Barney},
  title =    {Notes on Plato on the \mkbibemph{Kalon} and the Good},
  journaltitle = {Classical Philology},
  year =     2010,
  commentator =  {Paula Gottlieb},
  eprint =   {10.1086/657026, 10.1086/659326}, %the first number is
                                     % the article, the second one the
                                     % comment, which I want to appear in one entry
  eprinttype =   {jstor},
  volume =   105,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {363-77, 378-80} % the same as with eprint
  }

@Article{Derrida:Pharmacie1-1,
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  journaltitle = {Tel Quel},
  year =     1968,
  volume =   32,
  pages =    {3-48}
}

@Article{Derrida:Pharmacie1-2,
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  journaltitle = {Tel Quel},
  year =     1968,
  volume =   33,
  pages =    {18-59}
}

@InBook{Derrida:Pharmacie2,
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  year =     1993,
  bookauthor =   {Jacques Derrida},
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  gender =   {sm},
  booktitle =    {La Diss{\'e}mination},
  bookauthor =   {Jacques Derrida},
  publisher =    {{\'E}dition Points},
  location =     {Paris},
  pages =    {77-213}, % perhaps: {77-148, 149-213}
  related =  {Derrida:Pharmacie1-1}, % both articles are reprinted in one book,
                   % the unity of the deconstructed separation, which might duly be called 
                          % the voice of the separated unification as voiced deconstruction
                          % of no-pposites
  related =      {Derrida:Pharmacie1-2},
  relatedstring ={Nachdruck von}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sorting=nyvt,
            backend=biber, citetracker=constrict,
            opcittracker=constrict, 
            idemtracker=constrict, relatedformat=parens, 
            autolang=hyphen, clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyBib.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I separate the two keys with a comma in the Derrida-case, I get the reference two times, separated by a line-break.

Comment: It works fine, it just needs three runs: latex --> biber --> latex

Comment: In `Derrida:Pharmacie2`, you will have to put both related entry into one `related` field (separated by a comma, of course), otherwise Biber will only take the last occurrence of the field and will ignore all previous (I would have expected a warning by Biber, but there was none. You can see this behaviour very clearly, if you add a second (different) `author` field to an entry.). You might like to use `relatedtype = {reprintfrom}` or `relatedtype = {reprintof}` instead of manually specifying the `relatedstring`.

Comment: With your first problem of multiple DOIs (a similar question was asked before [Biblatex: online isbn versus print isbn](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103671/35864)), I actually think the current design is the right way to go. An article might well have different DOIs, a book might have two ISBNs - one for print and one for online publication -, but you only cite one of those: Only give the information of the source you actually cite. Also this would be quite hard to achieve since `eprint`, `url` and `doi` are verbatim fields by default, so the comma cannot be treated as a separator.

Comment: I'm not sure whether `Barney:Notes` is the actual real-world example where you would like to have two DOIs, but if it is: don't. The two DOIs refer two totally distinct articles. Granted, they both appear in the same issue of the same journal, deal with "to kalon" and "to agathon", and the latter is a reply to the former; but that's it - they certainly should not be crammed together into one entry. (Also I feel that Mrs. Gottlieb's work is not just a commentary, it is a "response" (cf. the title).) You might consider a separate entry for "Response to Barney" and add `related` info to it.

Comment: @moewe `Derrida:Pharmacie2`: >you will have to put both related entry into one related field (separated by a comma, of course) That's what I did, and that's the result: “La pharmacie de Platon”, in La Dissémination, Édition Points, Paris, pp. 77-
213; (Nachdruck von “La pharmacie de Platon”, Tel Quel, 32, pp. 3-48“La phar-
macie de Platon”, Tel Quel, 33, pp. 18-59.
“La pharmacie de Platon”, Tel Quel, 32, pp. 3-48“La pharmacie de Platon”, Tel
Quel, 33, pp. 18-59).  That's the problem. As I said, it prints _each_ of the related entries _two times_, neither separated by comma nor even space.

Comment: @moewe 
  flag
 
I'm not sure whether Barney:Notes is the actual real-world example where you would like to have two DOIs, but if it is: don't. The two DOIs refer two totally distinct articles. Granted, they both appear in the same issue of the same journal, deal with "to kalon" and "to agathon", and the latter is a reply to the former; but that's it - they certainly should not be crammed together into one entry.  <br/> I'd like to, as the bibliography is very large. Gottlieb will get only a `crossref` to p. 3.

Comment: I have added an answer for `Derrida:Pharmacie2`. Please comment if you want a different formatting or anything (the formatting in the answer is in the style of `standard.bbx`, not `philosophy-modern`).

Comment: Re `Barney:Notes`: I'd rather have a longer bibliography where Mrs Gottlieb gets properly mentioned as an author and not a commentator, than a confusing entry of two DOIs and page reference in one. (I would have suggested putting the two entries in one `@set`, see §3.11.5 *Entry Sets* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), but `philosophy-modern` really does not get along with `@set`s: It just ignored the set here.) An alternative solution would involve redefining the datamodel and all styles would probably not be worth it.

Comment: A longer bibliography where things can be found is better than a shorter one that is hard to use.  Bibliographies should be judged on their usefulness, not on their length...

Answer (score 4):

To get the two `crossref`s right, just put them into the same `crossref` field.
To cite my comment above

> you will have to put both related entries into one `related` field
>   (separated by a comma, of course), otherwise Biber will only take the
>   last occurrence of the field and will ignore all previous (I would
>   have expected a warning by Biber, but there was none. You can see this
>   behaviour very clearly if you add a second (different) `author` field
>   to an entry.)

```
@InBook{Derrida:Pharmacie2,
  title         = {La pharmacie de Platon},
  year          = 1993,
  bookauthor    = {Jacques Derrida},
  author        = {Jacques Derrida},
  gender        = {sm},
  booktitle     = {La Diss{\'e}mination},
  bookauthor    = {Jacques Derrida},
  publisher     = {{\'E}dition Points},
  location      = {Paris},
  pages         = {77-213}, % perhaps: {77-148, 149-213}
  related       = {Derrida:Pharmacie1-1,Derrida:Pharmacie1-2},
  relatedtype   = {reprintof},
  %relatedstring = {Nachdruck von}
}
```

Since you wrote `relatedstring ={Nachdruck von}`, `relatedtype = {reprintof}` seems fitting here.

It seems to me though that the `default` related macro in `biblatex-philosophy` is slightly messed up, `reprintof` also gets mangled, so we will have to tell `biblatex` what to do with it instead:

```
\newbibmacro*{related:reprintof}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\ifnameundef{savedauthor}
         {\ifnameundef{savededitor}
            {}
            {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}
               {\clearname{editor}}
               {}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}
            {\clearname{author}}
            {}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
       \ifbibmacroundef{date+extrayear}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%
          \renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
```

---

If we further redefine the standard `related:default` to

```
\renewbibmacro*{related:default}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\printnames{author}}%
       \iffieldsequal{savedjournaltitle}{journaltitle}%
         {\renewbibmacro*{journal}{\bibstring{ibidem}}%
          \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldsequal{savedvolume}{volume}} and test {\iffieldsequal{savednumber}{number}}}
            {\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{}}
            {}%
         }
         {}
       \ifnameundef{savedauthor}
         {\ifnameundef{savededitor}
            {}
            {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}
               {\clearname{editor}}
               {}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}
            {\clearname{author}}
            {}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
       \ifbibmacroundef{date+extrayear}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%
          \renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
```

**Update** `related:default` now prints an `ibidem` notice if the journal of the related entry is the same as the journal of the parent entry.

And treat the `Barney:Notes` as follows, note that `Gottlieb:response` is a `dataonly`, and the `related` field of `Barney:Notes` referring to `Gottlieb:response`

```
@Article{Barney:Notes,
  author =   {Rachel Barney},
  title =    {Notes on Plato on the \mkbibemph{Kalon} and the Good},
  journaltitle = {Classical Philology},
  year =     2010,
  doi =   {10.1086/657026},
  volume =   105,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {363-377},
  related={Gottlieb:response},
  relatedstring = {Commentary:},
}

@Article{Gottlieb:response,
  author =   {Paula Gottlieb},
  title =    {Response to Barney},
  journaltitle = {Classical Philology},
  year =     2010,
  doi =   {10.1086/659326},
  volume =   105,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {378-380},
  options = {dataonly},
}
```

We can get quite a desirable output, I think.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sorting=nyvt,
            backend=biber, citetracker=constrict,
            opcittracker=constrict,
            idemtracker=constrict, relatedformat=parens,
            autolang=hyphen, clearlang=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Barney:Notes,
  author =   {Rachel Barney},
  title =    {Notes on Plato on the \mkbibemph{Kalon} and the Good},
  journaltitle = {Classical Philology},
  year =     2010,
  doi =   {10.1086/657026},
  volume =   105,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {363-377},
  related={Gottlieb:response},
  relatedstring = {Commentary:},
}

@Article{Gottlieb:response,
  author =   {Paula Gottlieb},
  title =    {Response to Barney},
  journaltitle = {Classical Philology},
  year =     2010,
  doi =   {10.1086/659326},
  volume =   105,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {378-380},
  options = {dataonly},
}


@Article{Derrida:Pharmacie1-1,
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  journaltitle = {Tel Quel},
  year =     1968,
  volume =   32,
  pages =    {3-48}
}

@Article{Derrida:Pharmacie1-2,
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  journaltitle = {Tel Quel},
  year =     1968,
  volume =   33,
  pages =    {18-59}
}

@InBook{Derrida:Pharmacie2,
  title =    {La pharmacie de Platon},
  year =     1993,
  bookauthor =   {Jacques Derrida},
  author =   {Jacques Derrida},
  gender =   {sm},
  booktitle =    {La Diss{\'e}mination},
  bookauthor =   {Jacques Derrida},
  publisher =    {{\'E}dition Points},
  location =     {Paris},
  pages =    {77-213}, % perhaps: {77-148, 149-213}
  related =  {Derrida:Pharmacie1-1,Derrida:Pharmacie1-2},
  relatedtype = {reprintof},
  %relatedstring ={Nachdruck von}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newbibmacro*{related:reprintof}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\ifnameundef{savedauthor}
         {\ifnameundef{savededitor}
            {}
            {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}
               {\clearname{editor}}
               {}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}
            {\clearname{author}}
            {}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
       \ifbibmacroundef{date+extrayear}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%
          \renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\adddot\space}

%\renewbibmacro*{related:clearauthors}{}

\renewbibmacro*{related:default}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\printnames{author}}%
       \iffieldsequal{savedjournaltitle}{journaltitle}%
         {\renewbibmacro*{journal}{\bibstring{ibidem}}%
          \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldsequal{savedvolume}{volume}} and test {\iffieldsequal{savednumber}{number}}}
            {\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{}}
            {}%
         }
         {}
       \ifnameundef{savedauthor}
         {\ifnameundef{savededitor}
            {}
            {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}
               {\clearname{editor}}
               {}}}
         {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}
            {\clearname{author}}
            {}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
       \ifbibmacroundef{date+extrayear}
         {}
         {\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%
          \renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}}%
       \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solutions here might be somewhat fragile and might break in other use cases. But the default handling of related entries in `philosophy-modern` does seem to contain some bugs and sly redefinitions I had to counter.

Comment: Exellent! But isn't `idemtracker` supposed to do the job of what you get by redefining `related` with `savedauthor` ...? If `idemtracker` actually did it, then `ibidtracker` could replace *Classical Philology*, S. 378--380 by *ebd./ibid.*, S. 378--80.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Normally, `idemtracker` and friends are supposed to help shorten citations (esp. verbose citations), not the bibliography in itself. (Note though, that `idemtracker` will not help here as it compares `author`/`editor` names not journals.) It might be possible on a different route though, let me investigate.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann OK, have a look at the edited answer, if the `related` journal is the same as the parent entry's journal, `ibidem` is printed (strictly speaking this is not fully correct since ibidem normally refers to an entire work and not just a part of it, maybe `loccit` would have been better; I admit though in German it kind of works). I have not yet thoroughly analysed the implications of this change thanks to a lack of test cases, but let me know what you think.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann In the bibliography these `saved...` test take the role of a far more advanced kind of `...tracker` (`ibidtracker` would not help here, since it "[e]xpands to `true` if the entry currently being processed *is the same* as the last one, and to `false` otherwise.", p. 176, § 4.6.1 *Data Commands* of the [biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), emphasis mine).