# biblatex: Adding an editor as a series editor, not general editor

Tags: biblatex

my problem has to do with editors. I wish to cite an author's work. Said work is part of a series. Said series has its own editor (as is custom). I doubt, that said editor (Werner Hamacher) has in any way edited the books themselves. Unfortunately, if I merely qualify Mr. Hamacher as the editor, the following mess is produced:

Agamben, Giorgio (2009). What is an Apparatus? and other essays. Ed. by Werner Hamacher. Trans. by David Kishik and Stefan Pedatella. Meridian. Crossing Aesthetics. Stanford, CA: Stanford University Press.

This wrongly suggests, that Mr. Hamacher has edited the book itself. Is it possible, to change the order of this citation in such a way, that "Ed. by Werner Hamacher" is closer, ideally right next to, "Merdian. Crossing Aesthetics", which happens to be the series name. Is there a specific "series editor" that I've have overlooked?

I am using BibLaTeX and biber.

Comment: Tada: [Add new field to biblatex entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65374/35864). You could still define your own custom data model to get a `serieseditor` similar to [Biblatex: online isbn versus print isbn](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103671/35864) or [How to include price in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150404/35864). I would not recommend moving around the normal `editor` field, as I assume sometimes one does want to refer to the (normal/proper) editor of a particular work and not the series.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to define a special type of editor, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex.cfg}
  \ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
  \NewBibliographyString{serieseditor}
  \NewBibliographyString{byserieseditor}
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    byserieseditor              =   {series ed\adddotspace by},
    serieseditor                    =   {series ed\adddot},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{somebook,
    author      =   {Agamben, Giorgio},
    date            =   2009,
    title           =   {What is an Apparatus? and other essays},
    translator  =   {Kishik, David and Pedatella, Stefan},
    editor      =   {Hamacher, Werner},
    editortype  =   {serieseditor},
    series      =   {Crossing Aesthetics},
    location        =   {Stanford, CA},
    publisher       =   {Stanford University Press/Meridian}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \autocite{somebook}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: edited series]

But if you want to do more extensive surgery then you will need the kind of strategy recommended by moewe.