# Multiple ISBN's for a given entry, e.g. a book in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Please consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{p.bib}
  @book{Smith2015,
        title = {Some Conundrums},
        author = {Smith, John},
        year = {2015},
        isbn = {for printed version},
        isbn = {for online version}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{p.bib}
\nocite{Smith2015}
\begin{document} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is it possible using biblatex/biber to print multiple ISBN's for a given
entry, preferably prefixed with printed and online respectively. At present
the `online` isbn overwrites the printed one.

Comment: See also [Biblatex: online isbn versus print isbn](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103671/35864).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a mess.

Using `filecontents`, we write a new file that maps a data model for our new field `oisbn`. We *manually* add the `oisbn` field to the book-driver using a `biblatex-cfg` file. You have to make sure to add this to *all* drivers, if you want to have that feature for articles, incollections, etc. The additional toggle is just for convenience, if you decide to *not* include an online ISBN.

**Be careful, make sure to not simply replace any files! Check carefully and append the contents to any existing files.**

[image: pieterBiblatexField]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
    \ProvidesFile{biblatex-dm.cfg}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{oisbn}
    \endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex.cfg}
\newtoggle{bbx:oisbn}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{oisbn}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:oisbn}{#1}}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{oisbn}

\DeclareFieldFormat{oisbn}{{\color{red}online\mkbibacro{\space{}ISBN}\addcolon\space#1}}
\settoggle{bbx:oisbn}{true}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:oisbn}
    {\printfield{oisbn}}
    {no oisbn}%%%JB This is for debugging, make sure you don't have that in your real document
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
  \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Smith2015,
        title = {Some Conundrums},
        author = {Smith, John},
        year = {2015},
        isbn = {for printed version},
        oisbn = {for online version},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{Smith2015}
\begin{document} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```