# Why does biber say a checked-valid ISBN is invalid?

Tags: biber

I get the following warning:

```
WARN - ISBN '0-13-603313-X, 978-0-13-603313-4' in entry 'sheldon' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
```

But checking these ISBN against [this](http://www.hahnlibrary.net/libraries/isbncalc.html) and against [this](https://isbnsearch.org/), it seems to be quite valid.  What's up?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8):

There can only be one ISBN in the `isbn` field.

In

```
WARN - ISBN '0-13-603313-X, 978-0-13-603313-4' in entry 'sheldon' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
```

it looks awfully like you have two ISBNs in the `isbn` field as in

```
isbn = {0-13-603313-X, 978-0-13-603313-4},
```

Throw away one of the two ISBNs and Biber will stop complaining

```
isbn = {978-0-13-603313-4},
```

The same holds for the `url` and `doi` field. Here Biber will not complain, but the output will be mangled, especially when `hyperref` is loaded.

Comment: How applicable and possible would it be to assign more than one ISBN to a reference, either in the field `isbn` or by applying `isbn` multiple times?

Comment: @naphaneal You can't use a field multiple times. So that is out. And as I say, multiple ISBNs in the `isbn` fields are not intended and will cause a warning (they will probably print OK, so if you want to ignore the warning, fine). If you absolutely need a second ISBN, you need to use a new field: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103671/35864

Comment: @naphaneal  I fail to see how one would ever need several ISBNs. Pick ISBN-10 or ISBN-13 as it appears on the title page, if both are present prefer ISBN-13. If a book has a online and print ISBN use the one of the edition you used.

Comment: @moewe Hardback and paperback publications may have differing ISBNs even though the contents are the same.

Comment: @PeterWilson Fair enough. Still, I think normally it should be enough to just cite the ISBN of the version that you actually used. I can see that it might make sense to give several ISBNs for CVs or reading lists.